# Missing required parameter for [Route: ajax.offers.edit] [URI: ajax-offer/edit/{offer_id}] [Missing parameter: offer_id]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**Route code**

```
Route::get('edit/{offer_id}' , [App\Http\Controllers\OfferController::class, 'editOffer'])->name('ajax.offers.edit');
```

**Controller code**

```
public function editOffer(Request $request)
{
    $offer = Offer::find($request -> offer_id);
    if(!$offer)
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'msg' => 'Offer is not exist',
        ]);

    $offer =Offer::select('id', 'name_en', 'name_ar', 'price', 'details_en', 'details_ar')->find($request->offer_id);
    return view('ajaxoffers.edit', compact('offer'));
}
```

**View code**

```
<a href="{{route('ajax.offers.edit',$offer -> id)}}" class="delete_btn">Ajax Edit</a>
```

What's the problem

Comment: Fix you view code please

Comment: public function editOffer(Request $request, offer_id $offer_id) test to change the parameter in the function.

Comment: Edit your question and fix the Blade code snippet please

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your editOffer method add parameter `$offer_id` after `$request` like

```
public function editOffer(Request $request, $offer_id) { ... }
```

Second, when generating a link using `route()` helper function, you gotta add parameters in an array, not just as a secondary parameter directly. Like so:

```
<a href="{{route('ajax.offers.edit', ['offer_id' => $offer->id])}}" class="delete_btn">Ajax Edit</a>
```